# How to get the json data along with files from multiform/data in Node.js using Express framework?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, multipartform-data

I am able to upload files using multer
Now I want to parse the data from multiform/data like  [image]

The first four keys I am able to get by using the multer npm package in req.files object
The problem is that I want to get the "SHIVAY" key that has a value "SHIVAY" How can I do that ?

Also use headers Cores
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');

Also use url-encoded method

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

Also use json method

app.use(bodyParser.json());

Still unable to get any value
I hope I am able to elaborate my question
In advance thanks for the help  guys

Comment: usualy if you use `multer` your query data will be in `req.body` did you tried to use that ?

Comment: Yes. But not  getting that value